# Code coverage in react webapp

Tags: bdd, coverage, e2e, reactjs

I'm a little bit stuck with a task that I have been researching.
It's about code coverage in a react webapp.

I implemented a few unit tests using jest + enzyme. also some functional test, using cucumber to get gherkin features and puppeteer for browser automation.

I have able to get the coverage from the code built by webpack and served on my localhost using puppeteer and istanbul through functional tests.
Also, I get code coverage from unit test using jest (btw, it include istanbul to do that).

The problem is: I feel those are two diferents metrics, because I test components with jest + enzyme file by file, and in the other hand, I have code coverage from puppeteer that actually is a single built js file.

The goal should be get code coverage from unit tests and functional tests.

So, my questions are:

- has sense, mesure the code coverage on unit tests and functional tests?
- has sense, merge code coverage from unit tests and functional tests? and if has sense how to do that?
- what is the best aproach to get code coverage from a webapp?

Comment: Don't [cross post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55096175/3001761).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> has sense, mesure the code coverage on unit tests and functional
>   tests?

If you want to get 100% coverage it probably makes sense to measure a combination of unit, integration and functional end2end tests. Because some parts of integration are hard to test without a deployed version.

I do like to advocate for the least amount functional end2end tests possible. Just one or two per feature, because they are slowish, fragile, have a high maintenance cost. Now the added coverage will be so light that it might not be worth your time to combine coverage reports for just some extra lines. Personally I know which lines are covered by the end2end tests.

> I have code coverage from puppeteer that actually is a single built js
>   file

For code coverage purposes you could deploy a version that does not use a single built js-file.

> has sense, merge code coverage from unit tests and functional tests?
>   and if has sense how to do that?

If you can get source mapping to work you should be able to merge coverage even for front-end code that has been webpacked into a single file. But this is not documented well and might even need extra custom code to work well.

> what is the best aproach to get code coverage from a webapp?

This is too broad, but front-end code is similar to back-end code if you setup a testable architecture. Adding tests and coverage in a later stage will be harder, maybe use TDD ;-)